# CipherInputStream skips last byte when length is divisible by 16

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I've been playing around with encryption in Java, and I bumped upon strange behavior. When encrypting a `byte[] data` using

```
InputStream fin = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
CipherInputStream cin = new CipherInputStream(fin, mEcipher);
```

where mEcipher is a well-initialized AES cipher, this works always *except* when the length of the array is a multiple of 16. Then the encryption skips the last 16 bytes. I have to workaround it by adding an additional 16 0's, which can't be the intention since the encryption is done per block of 16 bytes so there is no need for the last bytes to be 0.

Below is a small example that demonstrates the behavior. Why is this happening and how can I fix it? It is only happening with encryption, decryption works fine (and there the length is always a multiple of 16). The routines `encrypt()` and `decrypt()` are written fully symmetric. I presume this a weird quirk in CipherInputStream, but I'd like to understand the details of it.

```
class Crypto {


String mPassword = null;
public final static int SALT_LEN = 8;
byte[] mInitVec = null;
byte[] mSalt = null;
Cipher mEcipher = null;
Cipher mDecipher = null;
private final int KEYLEN_BITS = 128; // see notes below where this is used.
private final int ITERATIONS = 65536;
private final int MAX_FILE_BUF = 1024;

public Crypto(String password) {mPassword = password;}
public byte[] getSalt() {return (mSalt);}
public byte[] getInitVec() {return (mInitVec);}

public void setupEncrypt() throws Exception {
    mSalt = new byte[SALT_LEN];
    SecureRandom rnd = new SecureRandom();
    rnd.nextBytes(mSalt);
    SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
    KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(mPassword.toCharArray(), mSalt, ITERATIONS, KEYLEN_BITS);
    SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
    SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");
    mEcipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    mEcipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret);
    AlgorithmParameters params = mEcipher.getParameters();
    mInitVec = params.getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();
}

public void setupDecrypt(String initvec, String salt) throws Exception {
    mSalt = decodeHex(salt.toCharArray());
    mInitVec = decodeHex(initvec.toCharArray());
    SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
    KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(mPassword.toCharArray(), mSalt, ITERATIONS, KEYLEN_BITS);
    SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
    SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");
    mDecipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    mDecipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret, new IvParameterSpec(mInitVec));
}

public byte[] decrypt(byte[] data) throws IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, IOException {
    byte[] decdata = new byte[data.length];
    int totalread = 0;
    int nread = 0;
    byte[] substr = new byte[16];
    InputStream fin = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
    CipherInputStream cin = new CipherInputStream(fin, mDecipher);
    while ((nread = cin.read(substr)) > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < nread; i++) decdata[totalread+i] = substr[i];
        totalread += nread;
    }
    fin.close();
    return decdata;
}

public byte[] encrypt(byte[] data) throws IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, IOException {
    System.out.println("data.length="+data.length);
    byte[] encdata = new byte[data.length+15-(data.length-1)%16];
    System.out.println("encdata.length="+encdata.length);
    int totalread = 0;
    int nread = 0;
    byte[] substr = new byte[16];
    InputStream fin = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
    CipherInputStream cin = new CipherInputStream(fin, mEcipher);
    while ((nread = cin.read(substr)) > 0 && totalread<data.length) {
        for (int i = 0; i < nread; i++) encdata[totalread+i] = substr[i];
        totalread += nread;
    }
    fin.close();
    return encdata;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String inpstr = "Dit is een test.Zit if een mewt.";

    Crypto en = new Crypto("mypassword");
    en.setupEncrypt();
    String iv = encodeHexString(en.getInitVec()).toUpperCase();
    String salt = encodeHexString(en.getSalt()).toUpperCase();
    byte[] inp = inpstr.getBytes();
    byte[] enc = en.encrypt(inp);
    System.out.println("In: "+Arrays.toString(inp));
    System.out.println("En: "+Arrays.toString(enc));

    Crypto dc = new Crypto("mypassword");
    dc.setupDecrypt(iv, salt);
    byte[] oup = dc.decrypt(enc);
    System.out.println("En: "+Arrays.toString(enc));
    System.out.println("Ou: "+Arrays.toString(oup));
}

public static final String DEFAULT_CHARSET_NAME = "UTF_8";
private static final char[] DIGITS_LOWER = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'};
private static final char[] DIGITS_UPPER = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'};

private static byte[] decodeHex(char[] data) {
    int len = data.length;
    if ((len & 0x01) != 0) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Odd number of characters.");
    }
    byte[] out = new byte[len >> 1];

    // two characters form the hex value.
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; j < len; i++) {
        int f = toDigit(data[j], j) << 4;
        j++;
        f = f | toDigit(data[j], j);
        j++;
        out[i] = (byte) (f & 0xFF);
    }

    return out;
}

private static char[] encodeHex(byte[] data) {
    return encodeHex(data, true);
}

private static char[] encodeHex(byte[] data, boolean toLowerCase) {
    return encodeHex(data, toLowerCase ? DIGITS_LOWER : DIGITS_UPPER);
}

private static char[] encodeHex(byte[] data, char[] toDigits) {
    int l = data.length;
    char[] out = new char[l << 1];
    // two characters form the hex value.
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < l; i++) {
        out[j++] = toDigits[(0xF0 & data[i]) >>> 4];
        out[j++] = toDigits[0x0F & data[i]];
    }
    return out;
}

private static String encodeHexString(byte[] data) {
    return new String(encodeHex(data));
}

private static int toDigit(char ch, int index) {
    int digit = Character.digit(ch, 16);
    if (digit == -1) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Illegal hexadecimal character " + ch + " at index " + index);
    }
    return digit;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using PKCS #5 padding, which means your output data will *always* be larger than your input data. If your input data is block-aligned (i.e. a multiple of sixteen bytes), you will get sixteen bytes of padding added. Your code assumed they would be equal in length.

I've corrected and simplified your encrypt and decrypt methods. Using a `ByteArrayOutputStream` avoids you needing to know the expected size of the output in both cases. I took the liberty of using try-with-resources statements, if you are using Java 6 or below you'll have to edit those out.

```
public byte[] decrypt(byte[] data) throws IllegalBlockSizeException,
    BadPaddingException, IOException {

  ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();    
  int nread = 0;
  byte[] substr = new byte[16];
  try (InputStream fin = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
      CipherInputStream cin = new CipherInputStream(fin, mDecipher)) {
    while ((nread = cin.read(substr)) > 0) {
      bos.write(substr, 0, nread);
    }

    return bos.toByteArray();
  }
}

public byte[] encrypt(byte[] data) throws IllegalBlockSizeException,
    BadPaddingException, IOException {
  System.out.println("data.length=" + data.length);
  ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

  int nread = 0;
  byte[] substr = new byte[16];
  try (ByteArrayInputStream fin = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
      CipherInputStream cin = new CipherInputStream(fin, mEcipher)) {
    while ((nread = cin.read(substr)) > 0) {
      bos.write(substr, 0, nread);
    }
    return bos.toByteArray();
  }
}
```